# CefSharp for WPF rendering squished controls

Tags: wpf, cefsharp

I am using CefSharp in WPF application, running it from VisualStudio works fine, but when deployed, the controls are squished.

Am I missing some resource?

[image: squished controls]

I am using version 73.1.130 from NuGet, installing on Windows 10 using msi installer created with Wix.

Comment: More information is required,  version,  operating system,  how you are deploying and to what. Check the log file https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Trouble-Shooting#log-file make sure you have deployed all the relevant resources,  https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Trouble-Shooting#dependencies

Comment: @amaitland you were right, I missed the locales

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to @amaitland I checked the included resources again and I found out, I missed the locales: locales*.pak - Localized strings for WebKit UI controls

turns out, they are quite important as the description says: Locales are conditionally required, features like context menus will show empty items without them. Fonts may show smaller than they should. The CEF documentation on the subject states: Without these files arbitrary Web components may display incorrectly.